# Angular - Busca valores iguais em dois objetos

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Bom dia pessoal,

Tenho dois objetos. Em um deles tenho somente o id. No outro vários campos, o id deste primeiro objeto e o nome.
Preciso de alguma forma varrer o objeto 2 achar o id igual que está no primeiro objeto para saber qual o nome dele, pois só tenho o id.

```
//objeto 1
$rootScope.obj1 = result.data.value;

//objeto 2
obj2 = result.data.value;
```

Exemplo de como fica no console do navegador:

```
//obj1
Object {id: 2, createdAt: "2017-12-22T14:01:35.225", updatedAt: "2017-12-22T14:01:35.225", name: "abc", initialDate: "2017-12-22"…}

//obj2
Object {......id: 2}
```

Desde já agradeço a colaboração

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de resolver isso é fazer um loop em um dos objetos e comparar os atributos:

```
var obj1 = { 
   id: 2,
   name: 'teste' 
};

var obj2 = { 
   id: 2 
};

for (var key in obj1) {
    if (obj1.id === obj2.id) alert("YAY");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agora estão clareando mais as coisas, muito obrigado.

Ficou assim:

var obj1 = $rootScope.objeto1;

```
       var obj2 = objeto2;


        for (var key in obj1) {
            if (obj1.id === obj2.id){
               $scope.Nome = obj1.nome;
            }
        }
```

Coloquei um alert dentro do if e apareceu dois registros. Porem como faço agora para que apareça o nome apareça na posição correta do array?

No console está aparecendo assim, conforme anexo[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: o `$rootScope.obj1` é o `obj1` do exemplo. Porém, se você quiser pode fazer simplesmente: `var obj1 = $rootScope.obj1;`. O que for mais simples para você.

Essa key é o índice do loop, geralmente o `i` do `for` tradicional. Se você quiser acessar um item especifico da lista, só usar obj1[key], por exemplo.

```
for (i=0; i < 10; i++)
for (var key in obj1) // duas formas de ver o índice usando for
```

Comment: Se voce estiver manipulando um `array` de objetos, só usar `indexOf` para você descobrir a posição onde exibir o nome.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

Comment: Percebi que só consigo comparar de fato os objetos se eu fizer a posição fixa:   if (obj1[1].id === obj2[1].id)

Answer (score 0):

Cheguei no seguinte cenário:

Consigo ver no console todos os registros

e a variavel nome está sendo preenchida. Porém preciso retornar o nome nas posições que o id foi igual.

var obj1 = $rootScope.objeto1;

```
       var obj2 = objeto2;

        for (var i = 0; i < obj1.length; i++) {
         for(var j = 0; j < obj2.length; j++){
            if (obj1[i].id === obj2[j].id){
               console.log(obj1[i].id);
               console.log(obj2[j].id);
               $scope.Nome = obj1[i].name;
            } }
        }
```

Obrigado pode fechar o tópico, resolvido movendo para o indice da grid